# Marketing & Promoting Your Community

Tags: communication, social-network

I'm starting a new online business which focuses heavily on media, but I'm not sure the best way to communicate with my audience and clients via social media.

A rough plan is to have multiple social networks for business purposes, but to have a single account to for making contact with people and communicating what's happening accross different areas of my business - Like so:

```
Business                             ...    @business
Business : Media Division            ...    @business_media
Business : Media Division : Brand    ...    @brandname

Administration For Media & Brands    ...    @_???
```

So should my Administration account reflect the business in some way (`@business_media_???`), or could it be a personal (`@my_name`)?

Any ideas on the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

There's two different situations where one might be better than another: if you're sending the email *personally* or for your business.

**If you're speaking on behalf of the business:** use `@business_media_???`. This way it's clearer that it's coming from the company and not *just* you.

**If you're speaking on behalf of only yourself:** use `@my_name`. This way it's clear that *you're* the one sending the email, not the company.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the thing that makes it difficult here is that it's a freelance business, so essentially I am the business - `@my_name` trading as `@business_media`. I think from a personal point of view it will be easier to communicate as `my_name`, but need to make sure I make it clear my posts written are from a business angle.

Comment: @W.H. in that case, you should still use `@business_media` since it's speaking for your company. Even if you're the only person in your company, it's clearer to have a company email.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether you want to build the brand around your name or your company. For freelancing, I personally think that using your own self as the brand has more advantage. Search for Chase Jarvis Photography or Neil Patel for SEO. If you are able to establish yourself as a leader in your field, **people will ask for YOU rather than a social media admin.**